# MISSING EXPRESSION WHILE VIRTUAL COLUMN IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to create virtual column but oracle says

`ORA-00936: MISSING EXPRESSION`

```
CREATE TABLE IPA_BOQ_ABSTRCT_DTL
(
  IPABD_ID      INTEGER,
  IPAEDH_ID     INTEGER,
  BCI_CODE      INTEGER,
  IPABD_PRV_QTY as (select count(*)  from cmn_mst)      
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this. To quote from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54465):

> #### Restrictions on Virtual Columns
>
> - Any columns referenced in column_expression must be defined on the same table.

A virtual column must be a scalar value on non-virtual columns defined in the same table.

Comment: Ben, I believe that's the same in `SQL Server` as well. Just an point.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the documentation for virtual columns [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54467).  There are various restrictions, including:

> Any columns referenced in column_expression must be defined on the same table.